# Call powershell function in file without dot sourcing

Tags: powershell

Is this possible if I only have one function in the file named the same as the file? I seem to remember reading about it before. Something like this:

hello.ps1

```
function hello {
    Write-Host 'Hello, world'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would get rid of the function call altogether.  You don't lose named parameters and cmdlet wrapping at all.  So this:

```
 function Hello
 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       $Message
    )
    Write-Host "Hello, $Message!"
 }
```

becomes:

```
 [CmdletBinding()]
 param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Message
 )
 Write-Host "Hello, $Message!"
```

And you can all it like this:

```
> .hello.ps1 "World"
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. This is awesome.

Answer (score 5):

By default, the function hello will only be accessible at *script scope* unless you dot-source the script. That means, once the script exits, it is no longer visible. If you want it available outside of hello.ps1 without dot-sourcing, you can declare the function at global scope:

```
function global:hello {
    Write-Host 'Hello, world' 
}
```

Then you can just execute the script and then call the function:

```
PS C:\temp> .\hello.ps1
PS C:\temp> hello
Hello, world
```

For more info on powershell scopes, [check out the help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315289.aspx).

If you want to just have the code in the function execute, just don't surround it by a function declaration. In `hello.ps1`:

```
    Write-Host 'Hello, world'
```

Then just call it:

```
PS C:\temp> .\hello.ps1
Hello, world
```

Comment: I ended up adding a call to the function at the end of every file. IE: `hello $args`. But if there's another way, I'd still love to know.

Comment: @cable729 you don't have to enclose your code in a function at all. See my update.

Comment: Another good option, but then you give up named parameters and cmdlet wrapping.

Comment: You can still use named parameters and cmdlet wrapping in a bare script.  Use the param() block syntax.