# First parameter in PowerShell function loses its value?

Tags: powershell

Here's a function that I call with `.\GetEMSInstallers`. For some unknown reason the first parameter always loses its value:

```
function Get-EMSInstallers {

param (
    $ems_for_amx_source = '\\server\ems_path',
    $installers_dir = 'D:\installers'
)

process {

    if (!(Test-Path "$installers_dir\EMS4AMX")) {
        "Copying files and folders from $ems_for_amx_source to $installers_dir\EMS4AMX"
        copy $ems_for_amx_source "$installers_dir\EMS4AMX" -rec -force
    }
}

}
Get-EMSInstallers $args
```

When I call it I get this output:

```
Copying files and folders from  to D:\installers\EMS4AMX
Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty array.
At C:\Users\ad_ctjares\Desktop\Scripts\Ems\GetEMSInstallers.ps1:12 char:17
+             copy <<<<  $ems_for_amx_source "$installers_dir\EMS4AMX" -rec -force
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyArrayNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyI
   temCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don't pass in any argument to Get-EMSInstallers you still have a $args array - it is just empty. So the $ems_for_amx_source parameters is set to this empty array.

In other words, one way around this:

```
if ($args)
{
  Get-EMSInstallers $args
}
else
{
  Get-EMSInstallers
}
```

There is probably a more powershelly way to do this - I might revise this later if it comes to mind. :-) But that will get you started anyway.

Comment: You can use [splatting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx) to pass all the values in an array to a function, instead of passing the array as a single argument: `Get-EMSInstallers @args` (or use the answer from the OP's other question and [declare the parameters on a script, instead of a nested function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11423516/2495) :).