# Supplied parameter is not recognized?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to import a module then execute it.

If I do this in powershell prompt, it works.

```
. "Z:\shm\Invoke-Runas.ps1"
Invoke-Runas -User a -Password a -Binary C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe -LoginType 0x1
```

However if I use a one liner, I got an error:

```
powershell -ep bypass . "Z:\shm\Invoke-Runas.ps1" ; Invoke-Runas -User a -Password a -Binary C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe -LoginType 0x1

Invoke-Runas : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'LoginTy
pe'.
At line:1 char:108
+ . Z:\shm\Invoke-Runas.ps1 ; Invoke-Runas -User a -Password a -Binary C:\Windo
ws\System32\cmd.exe -LoginType <<<<  0x1
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Runas], ParameterBi
   ndingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Invoke-Runas
```

It looks like the previous command ate all parameters, am I wrong?

[The source code is here](https://github.com/FuzzySecurity/PowerShell-Suite/blob/master/Invoke-Runas.ps1)

Comment: Yes, It literally ate all the parameters. :)  Put them in a single ps1 file and trigger it; That would be much easier than handling from the console.

Comment: @RanadipDutta so there's no way to solve it?

Comment: As a one liner? You can have a ps1 file and there you can do the operation; if you still want it as one liner then let me work on that for some time. Then I will get back to you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420554/call-powershell-function-in-file-without-dot-sourcing

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing it in an script block, then running the command with an ampersand in front to invoke it.

```
powershell -ep bypass -command & {. "Z:\shm\Invoke-Runas.ps1" ; Invoke-Runas -User a -Password a -Binary C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe -LoginType 0x1}
```